# Accesing related data in post_delete when removing in Django

Tags: django

When database object is deleted in Django the pre_delete and post_delete signals are dispatched before and after the delete action in database. In my project I delete objects which has related objects.

Connecting a callback to post_delete let me use data from the objects even if the object is not anymore in the database. However, as far as I know, this not happens with related objects.

To workaround this I connected a callback to pre_delete. This callback modifies the instance adding some info I will need at post_delete callback, but I wonder if there are a better way to do this.

Comment: Does what you did work well for you?

Comment: It works well, but, as Django follows DRY principles, and this is a common situation, I think it may be a better way to do it.

Comment: reading through your question I came to the same conclusion (grab what you need in pre_delete). Its works and isn't messy.